# how to implement publish subscribe push notification in android mobile device without polling

Tags: android, android-intent, android-c2dm, publish-subscribe, android-contentprovider

Is there any way to implement publish subscribe push notification in Android ?
At the same time, client(application running in mobile app) should not polling server for informtion,so  whenever there is update, server should publish the common message and the intended senders should receive it. (application running in a mobile app should not poll it)

Please guide me to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about multicasting a notification? if not, use google's C2DM servers.

Comment: no i need to push a single common message to more than one device at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to implement publish subscribe push notification in Android ?

Use [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/). Since C2DM does not guaranteed delivery, though, you still will want an occasional poll to make sure you did not miss any messages.

Anything else that does push and might have guaranteed delivery (e.g., an MQ server with something like RabbitMQ as a client) would require you to keep an Android service running all of the time. Users or the OS can get rid of your service when they desire.

Comment: ya thanks. If suppose i want to send a common message to all my subscribers or common message to more than one device at same time, Does C2DM support this?

Comment: and its been mentioned that C2DM push each message to eacch device one by one? is it not implemented in Publish/Subscribe?

Comment: @user149535: C2DM sends an individual message to an individual device. **All** "Publish/Subscribe" systems send individual messages to individual endpoints, because that is all that is possible from a networking standpoint. A true "Publish/Subscribe" system simply provides APIs that try to hide this from application code, making it *appear* that you are sending "a common message to all my subscribers" or are performing other bulk operations. C2DM does not have that sort of API, but you are welcome to write your own that layers on top of C2DM.